# How to concatenate flv file into one?

Tags: ffmpeg

There is a file named  input.txt

```sh
file '/home/1.flv'
file '/home/2.flv'
```

I can use the command to Concatenate  1.flv and 2.flv into a mp4 file.

```sh
# there are two files in output.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

When i use  the following command

```sh
ffmpeg -i "concat:1.flv|2.flv" -c copy output.mp4
```

I found the there is only one file `1.flv` in the `output.mp4`, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I found the there is only one file `1.flv` in the `output.mp4`. Why?

Your first command uses the [`concat` demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat). This can be used if you want to avoid re-encoding and when your inputs do not support file level concatenation. Using the demuxer requires that all files must have the same streams (same formats, same time base, etc.), but is a relatively recent addition so older ffmpeg builds will not have this feature.

Your second command uses the [`concat` protocol](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#concat) which requires your inputs to support file level concatenation (such as MPEG-1 video, MPEG-2 video, and DV). These are two different methods of concatenating (or "joining" as it is often called by users).

Also see [How to concatenate (join, merge) media files](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files) on the [FFmpeg Wiki](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki). I see you also asked this on ffmpeg-user where someone else also provided an answer: [[FFmpeg-user] can't concatenate the flv file](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-February/013441.html).

Comment: can you please write the command for merging more than 2 videos

Comment: @MuhammadTufail See the concat demuxer in [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Comment: do you know how to concat video in andorid using ffmpeg

Comment: @MuhammadTufail I don't have any Andorid experience, but I don't see why you couldn't use one of the methods in the link I provided.

Comment: I used all these method but not working in android.

Comment: @MuhammadTufail You can ask a new question and provide the details.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are using H.264, you need to
[**remux**](https://superuser.com/q/133413/joining-h264-without-re-encoding) them first.

```
ffmpeg -i q.mp4 -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb q.ts

ffmpeg -i r.mp4 -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb r.ts

ffmpeg -i "concat:q.ts|r.ts" -c copy -bsf aac_adtstoasc qr.mp4
```